# Azure secured connection for Load balancer?

Tags: azure

we are creating a virtual machines  in resource manager portal with internet facing load balancer. In virtual machines we have more than 10 web application running in different ports. we have port mapping in load balancer to access application as public. Now our requirement is how can we make secured connection for all applications? can we make "https" for load balancer public IP?

please let me know if any possibilities to make secure connection for loadbalancer.

Thanks,
Selva

Answer (score 0):

you can go with Azure application gateway to do the external SSL termination.Then setup an internal loadbalancer to do the routing. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/application-gateway-ssl-arm/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/application-gateway-ilb/